# Replace words between double brackets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I can receive 2 types of strings from the user.

1. `cmd1 = inst1.exe license.dat`
2. `cmd2 = {{installer}} {{license}}`

And I have to replace the strings between braces with something from a dictionary (`{'installer': 'inst1.exe', 'license': 'license.dat'}`)

I'm trying something like that:

```
def my_replace_method(cmd, dict)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        cmd.replace(key, value)
```

for call:

```
my_replace_method(cmd2, dict)
```

The output I got was: `"{{inst1.exe}} {{license.dat}}"` instead of `"inst1.exe license.dat"`

and

```
my_replace_method(cmd1, dict)
```

The output I got is `"inst1.exe license.dat.dat"` instead of `"inst1.exe license.dat"`

My expected output for both commands is:
inst1.exe license.dat
How can I write a method that works for both types of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `cmd.replace("{{"+key+"}}", value)` or `cmd.replace('{{%s}}'%key, value)`since using only `replace` replaces the text and *only* the text you give it.
So you need to include the braces if you want to match the braces too.

**Edit:**
The reasons for the two errors are as follows:

- The braces weren't in the old strings(aka You didn't replace the braces with the new strings), so they were left behind, hence the extra braces.
- Since your braces aren't in the old strings, Python replaces `license` with `license.dat` instead of replacing `{{licence}}` with  `license.dat`.So `license.dat` becomes `license.dat.dat`